# iisnode HTTP Error 500.0

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, iis, iisnode

I'm getting 500.0 error when trying to hit my server.js.  I've looked through all the related issues and tried suggested solutions, but I still can't get this to work. I am looking for some help.  It was working and then it stopped. Could it possibly be a web.config issue?

https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/3083282/983807/895e8922-087a-11e3-829a-6600da62cb7f.png

`<handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <iisnode nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1" debuggingEnabled="true" watchedFiles="*.js;node_modules\*;routes\*.js;views\*.jade" nodeProcessCommandLine="\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" loggingEnabled="true" debugHeaderEnabled="true" devErrorsEnabled="true"  />`

iisnode v 0.2.7.0    x64
node.js v 0.10.16.0  x86

There is an uncaughtException handler on my server.js and nothing is coming up.

Enable 32-Bit Applications: False

ETW trace:

- iisnode received a new http request
- iisnode failed to initialize a new node.exe process
- iisnode failed to initialize a new node.js application
- iisnode failed to create a new node.js application
- iisnode failed to process a new http request

Any help is greatly appreciated.